# How to do USB tethering using Android device which does not have SIM card?

Tags: tethering

I have an Android device which does not have place to insert a SIM card, can I tether this device to PC through USB (I want it to be fast, hence preferring USB over Wifi) in some way?

Comment: I think this question is extension of that Cam software question. So, do you not see the tethering option in your device? Which device and Android version is it?

Comment: Yes. I do not see tethering option. This a Epson Moverio BT-200, its AR glasses. Android 4.0.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We used [FoxFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi) and got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your device does not have tethering built in (Many devices do), you can get an app from the Play Store that allows you to tether your phone. There are several great applications that allow you to tether via USB or WiFi. 
A good app that solves this purpose is one called USB Tether
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mkdev.usbtethering2
Its simple and functional.

Comment: We used FoxFi and got it to work. Thanks for answer though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app whose minimum requirement is Android 4.0.3 . This app doesn't even require root access.

Install this application which will help you achieve USB tethering.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.hotspotcontrol&hl=en

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: For some reason, Hot Spot didn't work in the Android device. We used FoxFi.