# USB tethering without a SIM card

Tags: sim-card, accounts, usb-tethering

Why isn't this allowed? I'd like to use my brother's old phone to get on the Internet. It's the same model as mine (ZTE ZMAX PRO). He just recently passed away, and his last phone is being returned to the carrier.

Comment: And if not is there an app that will do it? I've tried a couple but all of them enable via the standard settings, which gets me nowhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://android.stackexchange.com/q/111456/116800